# Removing the old Anaconda and installing the new version with the old environments

Tags: anaconda, conda

As a result of updating to a new Anaconda release, I want to delete my old version and install from scratch the newly released Anaconda edition.

What are the most reliable ways to transfer old Anaconda environments to the most recent version without losing them?

Anaconda had previously been removed, but all my old environments were lost.

Answer (score 0):

Update to the latest Anaconda release with

```
conda update anaconda
```

This won't remove any of your environments.

But if you don't maintain environment.yml files for your environments,
they are worthless anyway and you can safely delete them. Hint:
Do you know the difference between the above command and

```
conda update all
```

?